# Using openSMILE with audio stream

Tags: audio, feature-extraction

I'm trying to use OpenSmile as feature extractor(using emobase2010.conf) and do some classification with that features.

What i'm curious about is whether if i can use stream of audio already made to list as input(I'm using ROS communication to get audio stream).

At manual of openSMILE it only has example of using .wav as input.

Or is there anyway to extract 1582 features(like emobase2010.conf) from audio other then using openSMILE?